# Excel empty string copy/paste values to nonblank cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Suppose we have a cell with an empty string `=""` in it. We copy the cell then PasteValues. The resulting cell appears blank, with no formulas, but is not a blank. Why does this happen? Also, if I want to perform numerical operations on a range of such cells, what would be the standard/best way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose

A1 `= ""` . We copy the value to B1 and then paste as values.

[image]

Now Select cell `C3` put cursor on formula input range and press F9.

[image]

It will appear as

[image]

**ISBLANK** function evaluates a cell that contains an empty string of text as False. ISBLANK thinks there’s something in the cell even though there is not.

Read more [here](http://www.excelfreedom.com/http:/www.excelfreedom.com/why-lena10-can-be-better-than-isblanka1/)

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is `zero-length string`. 
Remember that `zero-length string` is different from `empty`.

To do numerical operations in a range of cell like this, utilize the `Len` function
to distinguish it from other cells.